# Implementing Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a navigation in my application but have encountered a few problems that I cannot seem to get rid of.

When I try run the application I get the below error. I have tried changing the different imports for fragments, I have also tried extending the activity to extend Fragments but I\that gave even more errors and had to change it back to AppCompatActivity.

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
02-18 14:31:11.535 16698-16698/com.example.rory.pocketchef E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rory.pocketchef.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
```

**Lines implementing the navigation drawer**

```
drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
```

**Main Activity XML, for navigation drawer fragment**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.rory.pocketchef.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your activity.xml. Your DrawerLayout seems to be a CoordinatorLayout...

Comment: Done, I am using tabed views for different activities if that makes a difference

Comment: The issue seems to be in this line: `setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),` which you added `drawer_layout` from `CoordinatorLayout` and as `DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `CoordinatorLayout` if you want a `DrawerLayout`. Wrap your `CoordinatorLayout` in a DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Your stuff -->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

More Information can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Also, there is a good thing called `NavigationView` instead of `ListView` in new support library.

Comment: Sure, I just copied it from the android training and it can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will have a better look through the documentation before I ask another question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Your stuff -->
```

In your java, add the `DrawerLayout`'s id and not `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```

Comment: So all the normal layout stuff for main activity should be going in the nested CoordinatorLayout and then just what I have for the navigation fragment to be going into the DrawerLayout

Comment: Actually, the `Fragments` should be in the `CoordinatorLayout` and the porpuse of using `DrawerLayout` is, implementing `NavigationDrawer` So,your contents should be `CoordinatorLayout` as i noticed that in the comments on above codes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! +1